# Como faço para que um dado digitado em um input vá para uma função java script?

Tags: php, javascript, html, firebase

Como faço para que o dado digitado em um input de um formulário vá para uma variável ou que seja enxergado por essa variável, a variável em questão é:

`var emailAddress = "user@example.com";`

O formulário em questão é:

```
<form name="" class="list " id="">
    <ion-list class=" " id="signup-list3">
        <div class="app-icon"></div>
        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
            <span style="color: #9F9F9F;" class="input-label">E-mail</span>
            <input style="color: #ffffff;" ng-model="user.email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
        </label>
    </ion-list>
    <div style="width: 279px; height: 35px;" class="spacer"></div>
    <button ng-click="firebase.auth();" class=" button button-balanced  button-block  icon-left ion-ios-email-outline " style="border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;" id="">Enviar e-mail de redefinição</button>
    <button onclick="Mudarestado('item1', 'item2')" class="button button-balanced  button-block  icon-left ion-ios-email-outline ">Entrar</button>
</form>
```

Preciso que o e-mail digitado na input `<input style="color: #ffffff;" ng-model="user.email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">` seja enviado ao clicar no botão `<button ng-click="firebase.auth();" class=" button button-balanced  button-block  icon-left ion-ios-email-outline " style="border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;" id="">Enviar e-mail de redefinição</button>` o dado preencha do input e vá para variável `var emailAddress = "user@example.com";` permitindo assim que a função do botão informado anteriormente execute o envio do e-mail para o usuário.

Básica mente o problema e que não sei como posso fazer para que o dado digitado em uma input fique no lugar de `"user@example.com";` da variável `var emailAddress = "user@example.com";` para que o restante do script mande o e-mail para o usuário que digitou no input.

Atualmente esse script ta configurado para enviar o e-mail que já ta configurado nessa variável no caso do exemplo o user@example.com quando ocorre o clik do botão acima já mencionado.

Aqui segue o exemplo do script da duvida

```
var auth = firebase.auth();
var emailAddress = "user@example.com";

auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress).then(function() {
  // Email sent.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É simples, basta colocar no seu input uma função `onChange`. Ela será executada toda vez que seu input sofrer uma alteração.

Você pode fazer isso dessa forma:

```
<input style="color: #ffffff;" onchange="handleEmailChange(this.value)" ng-model="user.email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
```

e em seu script adicione a seguinte função de javascript:

`function handleEmailChange(email){
 emailAddress = email
}`

Comment: esse script teria que estar dentro da função `var auth = firebase.auth();
var emailAddress = "user@example.com";

auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress).then(function() {
  // Email sent.
}).catch(function(error) {
  // An error happened.
});` ???

Comment: Funcionou!!!  `function handleEmailChange(email){
var auth = firebase.auth();
emailAddress = email
auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress).then(function() {
}).catch(function(error) {
});
};`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o JQuery pra fazer isso. Primeiro você precisa dar um id pra esse input, por exemplo: `id="email"`

```
<input style="color: #ffffff;" ng-model="user.email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" id="email">
```

Então usando o a função `change`:

```
$('#email').change(function(){
    emailAddress = $(this).val();
}
```

Mas tenha certeza que você tem o JQuery no seu código:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Como eu faria essa aplicação no meu código?  poderia me dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com sua pergunta acho que falta alguns campos para preencher. Colocar o campo `name` na função:

```
<input style="color: #ffffff;" name="nomeDaVariavel" ng-model="user.email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
```

Colocar no form o tipo que vc quer passar e uma action que é para onde você quer passar:

```
<form type="POST" action="nomeDoArquivo.estensao" class="list" >
```

E trocar `var emailAddress = "user@example.com";`

por `var emailAddress = $_POST["nomeDaVariavel"];`

Comment: O problema e que por conta do `action=""`eu seria redirecionado.

Comment: Redireciona ele para a pagina que tenha o codigo depois redireciona dentro do codigo redireciona de volta.